# How to send SQL query to SparkSQL from a web application

Tags: spring, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spring-jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I have an application that performs SQL query on Spark DataFrame like this:

```
DataFrame sqlDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(accessLogs, ApacheAccessLog.class);
sqlDataFrame.registerTempTable("logs");
sqlContext.cacheTable("logs");

Row contentSizeStats = sqlContext.sql( "SELECT SUM(contentSize), COUNT(*), MIN(contentSize), MAX(contentSize) FROM logs")
                                 .javaRDD()
                                 .collect()
                                 .get(0);
```

I can submit this application to Spark by using `spark-submit`, it works totally fine.

But now what I want is to develop a web application (using Spring or other frameworks), users write SQL script in the front-end, click `Query` button, and then the web server send the SQL script to Apache Spark to perform the query action, just like what the `spark-submit` did above. After SQL execution I hope that Spark can send the result back to the web server.

In the official documentation it is mentioned that we can use Thrift JDBC/ODBC, but it only presents how to connect to Thrift server. There is no other information about how to perform query action. Did I miss anything? Is there any example that I can take a look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question needs to be reformulated, because it's too abroad, it's more related to Systems Architecture, and the answers may vary a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're looking for usage support, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Thrift JDBC/ODBC is better option. You can use HiveServer2 service

Here is the code

```
HiveContext hiveContext = SparkConnection.getHiveContext();
hiveContext.setConf("hive.server2.thrift.port","10002");
hiveContext.setConf("hive.server2.thrift.bind.host","192.168.1.25");
HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(hiveContext);
```

It will open a JDBC port. And via hive jdbc driver you can connect it.